# Calling locally defined function via function parameter

Tags: functions, let-binding

Interface, by example:

```
(my-run-command '(my-append (3 6 8) (4 5)))
```

Desired output:

```
(3 6 8 4 5)
```

Implementation, with bits missing:

```
(defun my-run-command (command)
  (let ((my-append 'append))
    […]))
```

*What should `[…]` be?*

I tried `(eval (cons 'funcall command))`, but that tries to evaluate `(3 6 8)`, which results in an error message.

Comment: Your question is unclear (to me). You don't even use argument `command` in your implementation. Maybe that's one of the missing bits, but it's hard to know what you're trying to do. A wild guess is that you should maybe be using `cl-flet` instead of `let`, but again, I have no idea what you're trying to do or asking. If you have trouble clarifying your question, consider showing more code and saying what you expect it to do and what it does that you don't want/expect.

Comment: Is there any reason you’re not able to use apply?

Comment: @Dan `let` does not bind the function definition to the symbol’s function cell. So the symbol cannot be executed as function with `apply`. I actually, did discover `flet` before asking the question, but I didn’t know that it needs to be called using `cl-flet` (although it is possible to enable an alias to `flet` – it works on my other system). Also, I didn’t know about `symbol-function` and `#'` which is part of the answer by @phils.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to alias a function name within the scope of the `my-run-command` body, so I'd suggest something more like:

```el
(defun my-run-command (command)
  (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'my-append) #'append))
    (apply command)))

(my-run-command '(my-append (3 6 8) (4 5)))
=> (3 6 8 4 5)
```